# Merging columns & rows with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure if this exactly possible but I thought I'd inquire. What I'm trying to do is combine two columns but have the data on two lines, for example given this df:

```
Column 1        Column 2
some data      more data
```

After combining them by doing:

```
df1["Column 3"] = df1["Column 1"] + df1["Column 2"]
```

Which results in:

```
Column 3
some datamore data
```

But I'd like it to display like the following:

```
Column 3
some data
more data
```

I'm exporting my data into an excel sheet so I'm not sure if there is a way to put the info in one cell, or it needs to be inserted in a new row. Any pointers are most welcome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
data = {'col1': ['some data'],
        'col2': ['more data']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

ie `df` is:

```
        col1       col2
0  some data  more data
```

Then you can do:

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame({'col3':pd.concat([df.col1,df.col2])})
```

`newdf` will be:

```
        col3
0  some data
0  more data
```

Comment: If this didn't solve the issue, let me know :)

Comment: this didn't quite solve my issue. I think because I'm working with an xlsx and the columns are already populated with info, I need to find another way. Thank you for the suggestion though!